# Chat like facebook in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have to implement chat option like facebook in my site. Please let me know any site which provide ready made tool or any article or tutorial.

Comment: To Minitech:- if you are not going to write it then don't comment on it. Just do your work and leave it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without Googling for you, I do not know of any sites that provide a "ready made tool" or an article/tutorial.

I would imagine that if you are aiming to create such a feature, you would be familiar with sending/receiving/handling data sent by a user, as well as assigning user IDs and handling sessions. Assuming you have knowledge of these operations, I will merely highlight a process that is likely to be new to you.

I would suggest using [long polling](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=long%20polling) to query a page for updates to the chat. This method involves the clients requesting (using AJAX) the contents of a page on your server, with your server not responding to the request until there are updates to be sent (or shortly before a timeout). This procedure allows the page to somewhat receive events, rather than checking for updates too frequently, hence lowering the amounts of requests that the users' browsers are required to make, and therefore also lowering the bandwidth usage of your feature.